# Terraform Use case for AppService

Tags: azure, terraform

I am asked to create Terraform Scripts for our Azure Infrastructure setup. For starters I am creating Terraform Scripts for AppService. For me I am confused with whole IaC paradigm and will like to know how it is done in an enterprise environment

1) Do we need to create seperate Terraform Scripts for each App Service. Or do we need to create one script and set the values as run time variables?

2) Do we need to have Terraform pipelines as separate or it should run along with Application deployment pipelines? That is,each time before Deployment of application, do we need to check for configuration drift via Terraform?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: 1) It always depends on how you want manifest the infrastructure.  You can create one scipt and give variables like a module concept or each one as separate. Best practice to use DRY and KISS.
2) I would prefer whenever a change in IaC (terraform files) it should trigger and check with your infrastructure, Other wise your deployment time will increase checking always with your infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

This question is basically opinion based. As per my experience,

1. you can have a single script file and have values injected dynamically
2. you can have terraform along with your deployment pipeline

Since you have mentioned that you are confused with IaC paradim, this article here might give more clarity. https://thorsten-hans.com/terraform-the-definitive-guide-for-azure-enthusiasts#the-terraform-lifecycle

hope this helps.